# Baseline of divs vs tables (for vertical-align purposes)

Tags: html, css

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UmLa4/5/).  Here's the relevant excerpt of code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div>fg</div>
    </div>hj</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <table><tr><td>
            fg
        </td></tr></table>
    </div>hj</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.box {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

See how the first example, there is no "descender gap" whilst there is an ugly gap in the last example.

This appears to be because the baseline of a div (or an arbitrary nesting of divs) is defined to be the baseline of the contained text.  But the baseline of a table is the bottom of the table.

Is this behaviour specified for all elements (not just divs and tables)?  Where?  Is it configurable?

Comment: Please rewrite your fiddle without inline styles.

Answer (score 2):

If you make a test with inline content on one side  and block content on the other, you have difference to happen.

set your table as an inline-table and reset its vertical-align to top or bottom, so it doesn't stand on the baseline.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UmLa4/6/)**

```
div, table, tr, td {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div.container {
    border: 1px solid green;
}
div.box {
    display:inline-block;
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background: #fee;
}
table {
    display:inline-table;/* keep its table-layout properties intact */
    width:100%;/* fill all width avalaible at least */
    border: 1px solid blue;
    vertical-align:top; /* or bottom to avoid gap under baseline*/
}
```

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know about display: inline-table.  It seems that the baseline of an inline-table is different to an inline-block element (eg. with vertical-align:baseline, inline-block does introduce the "descender gap" whereas inline-table does not).  But my question is: where is all this stuff specified?

Comment: @exclipy A simple element inline-block and a table inline-table involves more tags and layout propertis such as : border-collapse; border-spacing, inside and outside padding and layout. Some reset and your test aside a span inline-block and a table inline-table sharing basicly same rules : http://jsfiddle.net/UmLa4/8/ If you need to know more about this, you 'll have to go through W3C def for inline-block/inline-table , layout, borders, margins , ... :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your table property.
Try this:

```
table {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```